# Differential 2-form has a primitive...

Tags: real-analysis

Can anybody show me a proof of this theorem? : If a differential form of degree $2$ in $R^3$ has a primitive form of degree $1$ of class $C^2$, it also has a primitive form: $u \, dx + v \, dy$ where $u,v :R^3 \rightarrow R$.

Comment: Google Poincare lemma.

Comment: The Poincaré lemma is not germane, if I understand the question. I believe the question is to show that *if* the $2$-form $\omega$ is known to be exact, i.e., $\omega=d\eta$ for some $1$-form $\eta$, then we can find such an $\eta$ whose $dz$ coefficient is $0$.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I had this solution half typed out and then thought I had a counterexample. I don't. It's correct, although, interestingly, I've never seen this in my long career :)

I'm going to use subscripts for partial derivatives for ease of typing. I'm going to assume we're on all of $\mathbb R^3$ or at least a convex open subset.

Given $\eta = P\,dx+Q\,dy+R\,dz$, we want $\phi = u\,dx + v\,dy$ with $d\phi=d\eta$. So we need to find $u,v$ with
$$u_z = P_z - R_x\,, \quad v_z = Q_z-R_y\,, \quad \text{and} \quad v_x-u_y = Q_x-P_y\,.$$
We integrate the first two equations with respect to $z$, getting
\begin{align*}
u &= P - \int R_x\,dz + A \quad\text{ for some function }A=A(x,y) \text{ and}\\
v &= Q - \int R_y\,dz + B \quad\text{ for some function }B=B(x,y)\,.
\end{align*}
Then
$$v_x-u_y = Q_x - P_y - \int [R_{yx}-R_{xy}]\,dz + B_x-A_y\,.$$
By equality of mixed partials (here I'm using $\eta\in C^2$, hence $R\in C^2$), by choosing $B=A=0$, we see that we're done.

Comment: But, as I wrote, when the primitive ($\eta$) is $C^2$ it's ok, right? Because then $R$ is also $C^2$.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help!

Comment: Well. I'm sorry that after such a long time, but I've got one more question. While we compute for instance $v'_x$, we have: $(\int R_y dz)'_x$. How do we know that it's equal to $\int R_{yx} dz$? We have some theorems saying when we can do it, like Lebegue-Levy theorem, but can we use something like that here?

Comment: Yes, with the hypotheses we have here, there is no problem differentiating under the integral sign. Continuity of the partial derivative in question on a closed interval is more than enough.